# Проблема с рисованием в OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

По учёбе дали задание изучить OpenGL и нарисовать объект птица.

Голова с глазами рисуется,а вот 2 лапки(пусть пока недоработанные) и клюв(я решил конус использовать) не рисуются.

В чём может быть проблема?
Я приведу функцию где рисую птицу,если надо выложу весь код(с текстурами и всем всем)

```
void DrawScene(void)//прорисовка
{
    glTranslated(x, y, z);
    const double WidthPlatph = 3.37;
    const double HeightPlatph = 0.3;
    const double LengthPlatph = 10;
    const double WidthOpor = 0.2;
    const double LengthOpor = 0.5;
    const double HeightOpor = 1.7;
    const double RWireSphere = 1;
    glPushMatrix();

    //голова птицы
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[3]);
    GLUquadricObj *quadObj;
    quadObj = gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricTexture(quadObj, GL_TRUE);
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(quadObj, GLU_FILL);
    gluSphere(quadObj, 1, 15, 15);
    glTranslated(0,20,0);
    glRotated(270,1,0,0);
    gluDeleteQuadric(quadObj);

    // лапка1
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[2]);
    quadObj = gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricTexture(quadObj, GL_TRUE);
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(quadObj, GLU_FILL);
    glTranslated(2, 0.1, 2);
    glRotatef(90, 1, 0, 0);
    gluCylinder(quadObj, 0.2, 0.2, 2.5, 32, 32);
    gluDeleteQuadric(quadObj);

    //лапка 2
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[3]);
    quadObj = gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricTexture(quadObj, GL_TRUE);
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(quadObj, GLU_FILL);
    glTranslated(-4, 0, 0);
    gluCylinder(quadObj, 0.2, 0.2, 2.5, 32, 32);
    gluDeleteQuadric(quadObj);

    //клюв
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[4]);
    quadObj = gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricTexture(quadObj, GL_TRUE);
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(quadObj, GLU_FILL);
    glRotatef(90,0,-1,0);
    glTranslated(0,0,3.8);
    glRotatef(30,-1,0,0);   
    gluCylinder(quadObj, 0.7, 0, 4, 20, 40);
    gluDeleteQuadric(quadObj);
    glPopMatrix();

    angle+=1;
    glTranslated(-x, -y, -z);
}
```

Comment: Локализуйте проблему - у вас вообще получается нарисовать конусы - отдельно один кунус? Или они отдельно рисуются, а именно в компании - нет?

Comment: По отдельности рисуются,а вместе нет